# Delete directories with specific files in Bash Script

Tags: bash, find, xargs, rm

I would like to delete specific files if existed but also the directories that contain these files. I do know the files I would like to wipe but not the directories. So far, as I'm new in bash scripting, I think of this :

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.r*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf &> log_del.txt
find ./ -type f -name '*.c*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf &>> log_del.txt
```

At the moment, all files named with the specific extensions `*.r*` and `*.c*` are deleted.
But the directories are still remaining and also the subdirectories in it, if existed.
I also thought of the option `-o` in `find` to delete in one line :

```
find ./ -type f \( -name '*.r*' -o -name '*.c*' \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf &> log_del.txt
```

How can I do this?
And I also see that my `log_del.txt` file is empty... :-(

Comment: Do you want to remove the directories even if they contain other files?

Comment: yes, that's what I want. Deleting directories and their subdirectories after harvesting them. Some files remain in them (with specific extensions) but I don't care about these files because I have processed them a step before and secure information from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you really want is to remove all empty directories, recursively.

```
find . -type d -delete
```

`-delete` processes the directories in child-first order, so that a/b is deleted before a. If a given directory is not empty, `find` will just display an error and continue.

Comment: Can I use -depth AND -delete in the same line command ? I don't really understand the man. 1st I use -depth and if it's ok -delete will do the job with xargs ? I think also of VAR like this one to do the job with IF ELSE FI ...
`VAR4=$(find ./ -type f \( -name '*.r*' -o -name '*.c*' \) -print)`

Answer (score 0):

If the directories remain empty, let `rmdir` try to remove all of them. It will fail on any directories which have still files.

```
find ./ -type d -exec rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} 2>/dev/null \;
```

Comment: nice with the -exec option, maybe more efficient than xargs.

Answer (score 0):

See if this serves your requirement:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.r*' -delete -printf "%h\0" | xargs -0 rmdir
```

If the directory contained any other files, rmdir will fail.

So consider below sample file structure:

```
$ find a
a/
a/a/
a/a/4
a/b/
a/b/5
a/b/4
a/b/3
a/b/2
a/b/1

$ find a -type f -name '4' -delete -printf "%h\0" | xargs -0 -r rmdir
rmdir: failed to remove ‘a/b’: Directory not empty

$ find a
a
a/b
a/b/5
a/b/3
a/b/2
a/b/1
```

If in above example, you want to delete directory b also, you can simply use:

```
$ find ./ -type f -name '*.r*' -printf "%h\0" | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

EDIT: As per the comment, you (OP) wanted that the empty directory tree should also be deleted. These 2 commands should help you then:

```
$ find ./ -type f -name '*.r*' -delete # Delete matching files
$ find ./ -empty -type d -delete # Delete tree of empty directories
```

Comment: It's odd the -printf "%h\0" or -printf "%h\0\n" it returns only the non-empty directories and if i have 2 files with extension .r*, it returns 2 lines instead of just one. it also deleted only the subdirectories, not the subdirectories AND the directory that contain *.r* files. but it should with the -rf option in xargs command

Comment: `rm -rf` has a risk - you could end up deleting more **files** than you wanted. e.g. in above example, `a/b/5`, `a/b/3` etc.